# initializing slider on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, slider

im relatively a newbie to javascript. I'm helping a non profit with their webpage and since i knew a bit about html i volunteered. the template came with a javascript at the top that states:  Initialize each slider?? Im not quite sure where to do that to make it work once its uploaded to be published on the site. Can anyone point out what needs to be done in order for the slider to work like the template?? Currently the pictures are just still and stacked on top of each other on the page! Any help will be appreciated! website if anyone needs to look is militaryherosupport.org

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.coda-slider-2.0.js">    

<!-- Initialize each slider on the page. Each slider must have a unique id -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
   $('#coda-slider-2').codaSlider({
       autoSlide: true,
       autoSlideInterval: 6000,
       autoSlideStopWhenClicked: true   

   });
```

});

Comment: Just some general pointers on your website, try and pick a different background color. If the background color is to dark usually people will get drawn away from the actual content. Also the picture should probably be a .png so the white corners are gone(if you know how you could even make a slideshow of pictures to put up) Other than that it looks great. I'll check when its done.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation, you will need something like this:

```
<div class="coda-slider-2"  id="coda-slider-2">

    <div>
        <h2 class="title">Slide 1</h2> <!--you first slide title here-->
        <p>Content</p> <!--you first slide content here -->
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2 class="title">Slide 2</h2> <!--you 2nd slide title here-->
        <p>Content</p> <!--you 2nd slide content here-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the input! ill give it a try! and see if i can make it happen